# Write a program that calculates the minimum fixed monthly payment needed in order pay off a credit card balance within 12 months

Tags: python, python-2.7

This question is for python 2.7. The question asks to write a program that calculates the minimum fixed monthly payment needed in order pay off a credit card balance within 12 months.By a fixed monthly payment, we mean a single number which does not change each month, but instead is a constant amount that will be paid each month.

In this problem, we will not be dealing with a minimum monthly payment rate.

The following variables contain values as described below:
balance - the outstanding balance on the credit card
annualInterestRate - annual interest rate as a decimal

The program should print out one line: the lowest monthly payment that will pay off all debt in under 1 year.

Assume that the interest is compounded monthly according to the balance at the end of the month (after the payment for that month is made). The monthly payment must be a multiple of $10 and is the same for all months. Notice that it is possible for the balance to become negative using this payment scheme, which is okay. A summary of the required math is found below:

Monthly interest rate = (Annual interest rate) / 12
Updated balance each month = (Previous balance - Minimum monthly payment) x (1 + Monthly interest rate)

I came up with a code for the question; however, I repeatedly got an infinite loop.

```
    b = balance = 3329
    air = annualInterestRate = 0.2
    monthlyInterestRate = (air/12)
    mmp = minimumMonthlyPayment = (balance * monthlyInterestRate)
    month = 0
    while month <= 12:
        b = ((b - mmp) * (1 + (air/12)))
        month = 1 + month
        if b <= 0 and month == 12:
           break
        elif b > 0 and month == 12:
           b = balance
           month = 0
           mmp = minimumMonthlyPayment + 10.00
    print str('Lowest Payment: ' + str(round(mmp, 2)))
```

Can someone help me fix this code? For the given balance the lowest payment is 310...I'm not sure how to get this...

Answer (score 5):

```
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12
monthlyPayment = 0
newbalance = balance
while newbalance > 0:
    monthlyPayment += 10
    newbalance = balance
    month = 1

    while month <= 12 and newbalance > 0:
        newbalance -= monthlyPayment
        interest = monthlyInterestRate * newbalance
        newbalance += interest
        month += 1
    newbalance = round(newbalance,2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
monthlyPayment = 0
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate /12
newbalance = balance
month = 0

while newbalance > 0:
    monthlyPayment += 10
    newbalance = balance

    for month in range(1,13):
        newbalance -= monthlyPayment
        newbalance += monthlyInterestRate * newbalance
        month += 1
print " Lowest Payment:", monthlyPayment
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is a bit weird, namely lines like:

```
   mmp = minimumMonthlyPayment = (balance * monthlyInterestRate)
```

with the double equal signs.

This code doesn't get stuck:

```
balance = 5000
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyInterestRate = (annualInterestRate/12)
minimumMonthlyPayment = (balance * monthlyInterestRate)
month = 0
while month <= 12:
    balance = ((balance - minimumMonthlyPayment) * (1 + monthlyInterestRate))
     month = 1 + month
    if balance <= 0 and month == 12:
        break
    elif balance > 0 and month == 12:
        month = 0
        minimumMonthlyPayment + 1.00

print str('Lowest Payment: ' + str(round(minimumMonthlyPayment, 2)))
```

But doesn't return the answer you're looking for.

Comment: well the teacher puts in a number of things in place of balance and annualInterestRate as long as it checks correctly I'm fine...but the guess and check program (as you can see) isn't really written so well...

Comment: This last code (from Dan Steingart) doesn't work either, for example: balance = 4773, annualInterestRate = 0.2.
The result gives the value 450, instead of 440!!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to fix month <= 12
make it month < 12
secondly you are using a form which is not needed here
 balance = ((balance - minimumMonthlyPayment) * (1 + monthlyInterestRate))
because simply you don't have to use the minimum payment here
Your code is too bad

Try this:

```
    balance = 3329
    annualInterestRate = 0.2

    monthlyPayment = 10
    monthlyInterestRate = interestRate/12
    newbalance = balance - 10


    while newbalance > 0:
        monthlyPayment += 10
        newbalance = balance
        month = 0

        while month < 12 and newbalance > 0:

            month += 1
            interest = monthlyInterestRate * newbalance
            newbalance -= monthlyPayment
            newbalance += interest

    newbalance = round(newbalance,2)


    print " Lowest Payment:", monthlyPayment
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the right answer in all of the cases:

```
monthlyPayment = 10
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate /12
newbalance = balance - 10

while newbalance > 0:
    monthlyPayment += 10
    newbalance = balance
    month = 0

    while month < 12 and newbalance > 0:
        newbalance -= monthlyPayment
        interest = monthlyInterestRate * newbalance
        newbalance += interest
        month += 1
    newbalance = round(newbalance,2)
print " Lowest Payment:", monthlyPayment
```

Answer (score 1):

```
balance = 3329
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12
monthlyPayment = 0
newbalance = balance
while newbalance > 0:
monthlyPayment += 10
newbalance = balance
month = 1
while month <= 12 and newbalance > 0:
    newbalance -= monthlyPayment
    newbalance += (monthlyInterestRate * newbalance)
    month += 1    
print "Lowest Payment:",monthlyPayment
```

Think this will be the best solution to your doubt..and satisfies the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a fairly simple way of doing it:

```
x = 50
o = balance
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
monthly = annualInterestRate/12

while balance>0:
    for months in a:
        u = balance - x
        balance = u + (monthly * u)
    if balance > 0:
        x += 10
    else:
        break
print x
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a slightly improved version of randomizertech's answer, which allows user to input different variables instead of only doing it for fixed values of Initial balance and Annual interest rate.
And in the end it prints some more variables that would be useful to a user.

```
InitialBalance = float(raw_input("Enter your current balance: "))
InterestRate = float(raw_input("Enter the yearly interest rate as a decimal: "))


monthlyPayment = 0
monthlyInterestRate = InterestRate/12
balance = InitialBalance


while balance > 0:
    monthlyPayment += 10
    balance = InitialBalance
    numMonths = 0

    while numMonths < 12 and balance > 0:

        numMonths += 1

        interest = monthlyInterestRate * balance

        balance -= monthlyPayment

        balance += interest

    balance = round(balance,2)

print "RESULT"
print "Monthly payment to pay off debt in 1 year: " , monthlyPayment
print "Number of months need to pay the debt: " , numMonths
print "Balance after debt is paid: " , balance
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: Sorry, noob here. I was actually looking for a solution to a similar problem, where Monthly payment is obtained via bisection instead of being increased by 10. Then I ran into this so I just pasted what I had. Just realized very similar code was already posted too.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(12):
     balance = balance - (balance * monthlyPaymentRate) + ((balance - (balance * monthlyPaymentRate)) * (annualInterestRate/12))

print("Remaining balance:", round(balance, 2))
```

## Correct 10/10